# Connection to 'https:' was not upgraded to websocket

Tags: flutter, socket.io, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

I m using socket_io_client: ^2.0.0 this package integrates and connects socket io with my app but whenever run my code always shows the below message.

WebSocketException: Connection to 'https://api.xxx-xxs.com:0/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket#' was not upgraded to websocket

```
import 'package:socket_io_client/socket_io_client.dart' as IO;


Future<void> initSocket() async {
try {
  socket = IO.io(url, <String, dynamic>{
    'transports': ['websocket'],
    'autoConnect': false,
  });
  socket.connect();
  socket.onConnect((data) => {print('Connect: ${socket.id}')});
  socket.emit('/test', 'test');
  print(socket.connected);
} catch (e) {
  print("Error Socket: '$e'");
}}
```

Comment: Same issue here, did u find any workaround please